# Как в PyQt6 зажечь светодиод Arduino используя QSerialPort?

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt, arduino, pyqt6

Данный код работает для PyQT5, но не для PyQT6. Проблема где-то тут: **self.serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)**. **ReadWrite** нет в PyQT6. Помогите исправить код для работы с PyQT6.

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt6.uic import loadUi
from PyQt6.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo
from PyQt6.QtCore import QIODevice


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("Arduino_GUI.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('New')

        self.openB.clicked.connect(self.onOpen)
        self.closeB.clicked.connect(self.onClose)
        self.ledR.stateChanged.connect(self.led_Red)
        self.ledG.stateChanged.connect(self.led_Green)
        self.ledB.stateChanged.connect(self.led_Blue)
        self.led13on.clicked.connect(self.led13_on)
        self.led13off.clicked.connect(self.led13_off)

        self.serial = QSerialPort()
        self.serial.setBaudRate(115200)
        portList = []
        ports = QSerialPortInfo().availablePorts()
        for port in ports:
            portList.append(port.portName())
        print(portList)
        self.comL.addItems(portList)

    def onOpen(self):
        print('on')
        self.serial.setPortName(self.comL.currentText())
        self.serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)

    def serialSend(self, data): # список int
        txs = ""
        for val in data:
            txs += str(val)
            txs += ','
        txs = txs[:-1]
        txs += ';'
        self.serial.write(txs.encode())

    def onClose(self):
        print('close')
        self.serial.close()

    def led13_on(self):
        val = 1
        self.serialSend([0, val])

    def led13_off(self):
        val = 0
        self.serialSend([0, val])

    def led_Red(self, val):
        self.serialSend([1, val])

    def led_Green(self, val):
        self.serialSend([2, val])

    def led_Blue(self,  val):
        self.serialSend([3, val])

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

***Arduino_GUI.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>208</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>331</width>
      <height>61</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>Открытие / закрытие порта</string>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QComboBox" name="comL"/>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="openB">
       <property name="text">
        <string>OPEN</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="closeB">
       <property name="text">
        <string>CLOSE</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QCheckBox" name="ledR">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>LED_R</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QCheckBox" name="ledG">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>140</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>LED_G</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QCheckBox" name="ledB">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>240</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>LED_B</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="led13on">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>410</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PIN13_on</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="led13off">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>530</x>
      <y>120</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PIN13_off</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Библиотеки для Serial порта ардуины на сайте **alexgyver.ru** или на канале **"Записки Ардуинщика"**

***Скетч***

```
#define LED_R 5
#define LED_G 6
#define LED_B 11

#include "Parser.h"
#include "AsyncStream.h"  // асинхронное чтение сериал
AsyncStream<50> serial(&Serial, ';');   // указываем обработчик и стоп символ


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(13, 1);
  pinMode(LED_R, 1);
  pinMode(LED_G, 1);
  pinMode(LED_B, 1);
}

// с пк на ардуино, терминтаор ;
// 0,лед 13
// 1,r
// 2,g
// 3,b

void loop() {
  parsing();
}  

// функция парсинга, опрашивать в лупе
void parsing() {
  if (serial.available()) {
    Parser data(serial.buf, ',');  // отдаём парсеру
    int ints[10];           // массив для численных данных
    data.parseInts(ints);   // парсим в него

    switch (ints[0]) {
      case 0: digitalWrite(13, ints[1]);
        break;
      case 1:
        digitalWrite(LED_R, ints[1]);
        break;
      case 2:
        digitalWrite(LED_G, ints[1]);
        break;
      case 3:
        digitalWrite(LED_B, ints[1]);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено:

***self.serial.open(QIODevice.OpenModeFlag.ReadWrite)***